# Kafka broker in read only mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have 3 broker Kafka cluster, and what I am looking is to set any 1 broker in ready only mode.
I did checked Kafka documentation but did not find any config to do this.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Update**

**My Use Case:**

**Current state**:
I have a 3 broker kafka cluster running in healthy state.

**What to achieve**: I want to update the hardware of all 3 brokers.

**What I am trying**:

- Launch 3 new brokers, and let them join the cluster (cluster of 6)
- Use reassign-partition tool to migrate data from old brokers to new brokers
- Once successfully completed above operation, then terminate old 3 brokers

I did verified this, and its working fine, I can see all my data moved successfully to new brokers.

.
.

**What is the challenge**:

I do have clients(producer and consumer) accessing this cluster. I want the above activity to be **NON-DOWNTIME**(I mean I should not loose any of the client data, also existing clients should be able to access service)

The thing I am digging currently is - what if a client make a request to create a new topic at the exact same time when data migration is in progress.

**Will this happen?**

Partitions of new topic may go to old brokers, and as data reassignment is in-progress, this topic will not be reassigned.(I know it can go to new brokers as well, but what if all partitions are assigned to old brokers)

So if I terminate old brokers, then will I loose the newly created topic ?

**Hence**

So that is why I was looking for a way - by which I can make sure that the partitions of new topic are placed to new brokers(similar to put the old brokers in read only mode)

Comment: Could you elaborate your use-case as to why you would want to do this?

Comment: @JavaTechnical- Added my use case.

Comment: Did you try pushing new data while keeping the reassignment in progress? I suppose that the topic metadata update notification will come to your clients and then they re-read/produce the data from/to the new brokers.

Comment: @JavaTechnical- let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You can not set broker in read only mode.
Kafka broker doesn't support read only mode.

Comment: Added my use case in update, if you can spread some light on it, that would be super helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable topic creation by this setting auto.create.topics.enable
Then enable it again after the migration